# Why does 0.3 - 0.2 - 0.1 not equals to 0 in javascript?

Tags: javascript, precision

I get the result `-2.7755575615628914e-17` when my code `0.3 - 0.2 - 0.1` runs in Google Chrome browser. Why? and what does the `wrong` result stand for?

Comment: `-2.7...e-17` is scientific notation for `-0.000000000000000027...`. So, very very *very* close to 0.

Comment: 0.3 - 0.2 = 
0.09999999999999998 and then (0.09999999999999998-0.1) resulted into -2.7755575615628914e-17